# How to make a setup file with my own folders

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on a game in Raylib in Visual Studio 2022 and it's near complition I found some tutorials on yt on how to make a setup file.

But the thing is that when I install the game it doesn't include my resources folder with graphics and sounds so I'm wondering how to do it?